# ¿Es posible, crear una columna de búsqueda (LookUp) en una lista de SharePoint y que me filtre o me muestre ciertos datos?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Tengo una lista de SharePoint llamada **"X"**, esta lista tiene una columna de búsqueda que trae la información de otra lista llamada **"Y"**. Sin embargo, quiero que esta columna de búsqueda de la lista **"X"**, al crear un elemento me traiga o me muestre únicamente los elementos de la lista **"Y"** cuyos elementos en la columna **"Estado"** sean igual a **"En ejecución"** ¿Es posible hacer esto? y si lo es ¿cómo se haría?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.